# Angular4 Delete and Put Api Call Method not Found https status 405

Tags: angular, c#-4.0

I am working on CRUD operation in angular4 i have done get and post api call but when i am going to call delete and put api that time getting error, **405 (Method Not Allowed),Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405** 
 here is code:

```
service.ts
delete(url: string, id: number): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
    return this._http.delete(url+id) 
        .map((response:Response) => <any>response.json())
    }
component.ts
this._userservice.delete("http://webapiapp.apphb.com/api/task", formData.value.taskid).subscribe(
                data => {
                  alert(data);
                    if (data == 1) 
                    {
                        this.title = "Data successfully added.";
                        this.loaduser();
                    }
                    else {
                        this.title = "There is some issue "
                    }
      })
```

can you plz help me to solve this the api developed in MVC using C# i alos d efine all CROS in web.config with POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTION.

but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 return this._http.delete(url+id)
```

To:

```
 return this._http.delete(url+'/'+id)
```

Comment: While those code snippets may answer the OP's question, it is recommended to add some descriptional text to your answer, as it may help others.

Comment: still getting same error -zone.js:2933 OPTIONS http://webapiapp.apphb.com/api/task//68 405 (Method Not Allowed)